# How to save arima model to json

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, arima

I have read a lot [about pickle](https://www.smartfile.com/blog/python-pickle-security-problems-and-solutions/) and I do believe that Json would be the better serialization format for my prediction model. Is there a way to save an ARIMA model to .json? I tried with [sklearn-json](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-json/) but the current version does not support ARIMA models.

Comment: does [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-arima-time-series-forecasting-model-python/) help?

Comment: @saurjog actually does! now that I know it has it's own save method I can tweak it a bit. Thank you.

Comment: how did you end up tweaking it? trying to figure out how to store it as json too